# MySQL has two different passwords?

Tags: php, mysql, mamp, mamp-pro

I am sure they are passwords to different things but i am not sure what. When in terminal to connect to MySQL I enter `/usr/LOCAL/mysql/BIN/mysql -h host -u username -p` I am then prompted for a password and the password is `''`. But when connecting to MySQL with PHP I use the following code and it works

```
DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
DEFINE('DB_USER', 'root'); 
DEFINE('DB_PASS', 'root'); 

$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS,) or 
die('could not connect: '. mysqli_connect_error() );
```

If i were to use `DEFINE('DB_PASS', '');` it returns "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)", why does there appear to be two separate passwords?

Comment: What are you using for `host` and `username` at the command line? Are they `localhost` and `root`?

Comment: The answers below are right on spot. If you would like to make their password consistent, you could run `select password from mysql.user where user='username' and host='localhost'`. Copy the password. Then run `update mysql.user set password='<copied password>' where user='username'`. Now the passwords should be consistent for the user.

Comment: Accept the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 10):

**Q:** Why does there appear to be two separate passwords?

**A:** Because you are connecting as two *different* users.

Each user has its own password and privileges.

A MySQL database "user" is identified by *two* parts: the user **name** and the **host**.

For example, these are three distinct users:

```
'username'@'localhost'
'username'@'127.0.0.1'
'username'@'%'
```

To view the users defined on your database, you can query `mysql.user` table, e.g.

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user ;
```

You might want to review the relevant section of the MySQL Reference Manual.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html

NOTE: A value **`localhost`** in the `mysql.user` table or a connection is **not** synonymous with the TCP loopback address (127.0.0.1). It does not resolve to that IP address, or any other IP address. It's a *special* value.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL uses $user/$host/$password comparison by default, so your current setup has two different user accounts in MySQL - root and whatever username you supply on the command line. Each of those has its own password.

Also, if the account has no (ie empty) password you don't need to specify the -p flag on the CLI